# Regex for parsing http request

Tags: php, regex, http

I am trying to parse the HTTP request with the following code:

```
$request="GET /index.html HTTP/1.1";
$methods="GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS";
$pattern="/(^".$methods.")\s+(\S+)\s+(HTTP)/";
list($method,$uri,$http)=preg_split($pattern,$request);
print $method.$uri.$http;
```

Print does not return anything. I tried different modifications,but wasn't able to. I think the problem is with the regex. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `preg_split()`, you may want to use `preg_match()`, and move the `^` outside the parens.

```
$request="GET /index.html HTTP/1.1";
$methods="GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS";
$pattern="/^(".$methods.")\s+(\S+)\s+(HTTP)/";
//-------^^^^

$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $request, $matches);
print_r($matches);

// To get it back to the form you wanted...
array_shift($matches);
list($method, $uri, $http) = $matches;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the `^` is inside or outside the parentheses: it is a zero-width match and won't affect the result.

Comment: Don't put the method names into the regexp; there are more methods than these.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to simply split the request on whitespace.

```
list($method, $uri, $http) = preg_split('/\s+/', $request);
```

will produce the same result, except that `$http` will be `HTTP/1.1` which may or may not be what you want in the first place.